# I'm unable to open Flutter project in Visual Studio

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, flutter, ide

I can  open this project in Android studio and IntelliJ but when i trying to open existing Flutter project in Visual Studio that project folder opens but project assembly is not opening in IDE. I have attached it Screenshoots below. Thank you in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible run Flutter in Visual Studio

You must to use the VS Code and to open a folder or a workspace.

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio and Vusial Studio Code are two different softwares.

Comment: It is impossible to run Flutter in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use Visual Studio to do flutter development, If it's possible, I haven't heard of it.

The closest you can get to Visual Studio is by using Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 1):

You will open VS Code go-to **File > Open Folder** and then Select a folder you want to open

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the terminal, open up terminal and cd into the directory where your project is and then run the command

```
code .
```

this will open up vs code for that project folder,
This command works for linux distros and windows not sure about mac os. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: Visual studio is not supported for flutter projects.

**Alternative**: Visual Studio Code is supported

[Link to download visual studio code from here](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)

[image]

[image]